# js prototype table creation

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I am using prototype in my application for making javascript calls and updating data on the screen. My question is, when I'm trying to create a table, I saw an example:

```
    var tableProto = new Element('table').update('<thead><tr><th>Situation Task</th><th>Action</th><th>Result</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td></tr></tbody>');
```

With this tableProto element, how do I put it inside of a div on the page?

```
    var tableProto = new Element('table').update('<thead><tr><th>Situation Task</th><th>Action</th><th>Result</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td></tr></tbody>');
$('tableDiv').update(tableProto);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have a `<div id="mydiv"></div>` with your table element in the `tableProto` variable.

```
$('mydiv').update(tableProto);
```

Will replace the contents of the div with the table.

```
$('mydiv').insert(tableProto);
```

will insert the table after all the content in the div.